# how to solve this optimization problem with functions?

Tags: optimization, derivatives, functional-equations, calculus-of-variations, nonlinear-optimization

Suppose  $\theta\in[0,1]$ and $s(\cdot)$ is strictly increasing in $\theta$ with $0\leq(0)<s(1)\leq1$ and $s(0)+s(1)>1$

How could I solve the program,

$\max_{s(\cdot)\in C[0,1]}=\int_0^{s^{-1}(1-s(0))} \left(s(0)[s^{-1}(1-s(0))]+\int_0^{\theta} (1-s^{-1}(1-s(x)))dx\right) d \theta +\int_{s^{-1}(1-s(0))}^1 \theta d\theta$

$=  s(0)(s^{-1}(1-s(0))^2-\int_0^{s^{-1}(1-s(0))}\int_0^{\theta}s^{-1}(1-s(x))dxd \theta +\frac{1}{2} 
 =  s(0)(s^{-1}(1-s(0))^2-\int_0^{s^{-1}(1-s(0))}\left(\int_x^{s^{-1}(1-s(0))}d \theta \right)s^{-1}(1-s(x))dx +\frac{1}{2} 
  =   s(0)(s^{-1}(1-s(0))^2-\int_0^{s^{-1}(1-s(0))}[s^{-1}(1-s(0))-x]s^{-1}(1-s(x))dx +\frac{1}{2}$

I continue like this:

Let $g(x)=s^{-1}(1-s(x))$, then  $s(x)+s(g(x))=1$.  $ s^{-1}(1-s(0))=g(0)$. Because $s(\cdot)$ is strictly increasing, $g(\cdot)$ is strictly decreasing, $s(0)=G(g(0))$ is uniquely determined by $g(\cdot)$.
We have

$\max_{g(\cdot)\in C[0,1]} U_i(\theta; s)=G(g(0))[g(0)]^2-\int_0^{g(0)}(g(0)-x)g(x)dx+\frac{1}{2}$

s.t. $s(x)+s(g(x))=1$ and $s(0)=G(g(0))$.  Then I don't know how to proceed ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As a somewhat simple-minded start,

$\begin{align}
&\int_0^{s^{-1}(1-s(0))} \left(s(0)[s^{-1}(1-s(0))]+\int_0^{\theta} (1-s^{-1}(1-s(x)))dx\right) d \theta +\int_{s^{-1}(1-s(0))}^1 \theta d\theta\\
&=\int_0^{s^{-1}(1-s(0))} s(0)[s^{-1}(1-s(0))]d \theta
+\int_0^{s^{-1}(1-s(0))}\int_0^{\theta} (1-s^{-1}(1-s(x)))dxd \theta
+\frac{\theta^2}{2}\big|_{s^{-1}(1-s(0))}^1 \theta d\theta\\
&= s(0)(s^{-1}(1-s(0))^2
+\int_0^{s^{-1}(1-s(0))}\int_0^{\theta} (1-s^{-1}(1-s(x)))dxd \theta
+\frac{1-(s^{-1}(1-s(0)) )^2}{2} \\
\end{align}
$

The remaining integral
can be similarly manipulated
as

$\begin{align}
\int_0^{s^{-1}(1-s(0))}\int_0^{\theta} (1-s^{-1}(1-s(x)))dxd \theta
&=\int_0^{s^{-1}(1-s(0))}\int_0^{\theta}1dxd \theta
\\ &\quad -\int_0^{s^{-1}(1-s(0))}\int_0^{\theta}s^{-1}(1-s(x)))dxd \theta\\
&=\int_0^{s^{-1}(1-s(0))}\theta d \theta
\\ &\quad -\int_0^{s^{-1}(1-s(0))}\int_0^{\theta}s^{-1}(1-s(x)))dxd \theta\\
&=\frac{(s^{-1}(1-s(0)))^2}{2}
\\ &\quad -\int_0^{s^{-1}(1-s(0))}\int_0^{\theta}s^{-1}(1-s(x)))dxd \theta\\
\end{align}
$

Combining this, I get

$s(0)(s^{-1}(1-s(0))^2
+\frac{(s^{-1}(1-s(0)))^2}{2}
  -\int_0^{s^{-1}(1-s(0))}\int_0^{\theta}s^{-1}(1-s(x)))dxd \theta
+\frac{1-(s^{-1}(1-s(0)) )^2}{2} \\
=s(0)(s^{-1}(1-s(0))^2
+\frac12
-\int_0^{s^{-1}(1-s(0))}\int_0^{\theta}s^{-1}(1-s(x)))dxd \theta
$.

I don't have the slightest idea what to do with this.